# How to leave identical ammount of space between each CTRL+R Cut? AND why can I only do 1 cut?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

1. When you've cut something with ctrl + r, but not every cut leaves the same ammount of room inbetween each of the cuts, how do you fix that? (see picture with half assed arrow drawings)
   [image]

And

2. Why am I only offered one cut on the top instead of a full line (see picture and marked blue spots and red circle)

[image]

Scrolling doesn't fix it, as it only adds more cuts on the vertical face, instead of continuing a horizontal cut:

[image]

Comment: Please don't make users go through many links just to understand your quetsion. Use the  [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: The faces aren't joined, or one of the faces on the surface adjacent to where the cut gets interrupted, is a triangle. The loop cannot continue because of a lack of quad surfaces or because of a lack of joined edges. It's entirely possible that the edges are separate where the loop should continue, or and the two edges on the sizes of the adgacent edge, parallel to the loop, are still connected. You really have to go into vertex mode and figure it out by selecting verts and moving them.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Alt R to make a loop cut you get that purple loop of edges - then you click once and there will be an actual cut where the purple guides were. If you move the mouse you'll slide that loop and it will stay where it is once you click again.

If you want several evenly spaced loops you need to hold the mouse still between the two clicks, then change the number where it says Number of Cuts in the tool panel near the bottom.

[image]

Edit 2:
Remove edge loops by being in Edit mode, Edges, and right click, while holding down Alt, on an edge that runs in the direction of your edge loop - that will select the loop. Then press Delete and choose Dissolve Edges.

Vertices are points in space with XYZ coordinates - for example, in the middle of the world the vertex would be 0,0,0. There is a vertex at both ends of an Edge-  they define where the edge starts and ends.  There are many things you can accidentally do that will duplicate Edges and Vertices - there are lots of shortcuts that you can accidentally press which do all sorts of things.

To find these double edges or vertices, press A until nothing is selected, then you can use Border select - press B and drag a square around the suspected edge or vertex. Right up the top of the screen it shows details about the geometry including how many edges or vertices are selected - if you only see one, but it says at the top that 2 are selected, you know you have a double one (or triple one).  Reading the manual from the beginning helps get an understanding of all this.

About the last question, if you make one Alt R cut it will make it exactly in the middle between the other loops UNLESS you move the mouse between two clicks, in which case it will slide. If you finish that action and make a new loop it will again be half way between two loops. If you want to evenly divide a face with many cuts, delete the ones that are there and start again - click twice so you don't slide, then immediately enter a number in the Number of Cuts field.

Comment: Doesn't "number of cuts" just imply that it'll do the same as if I scrolled to get more cuts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "scrolling to get more cuts" - what do you do to scroll?  Anyway, try it - if it does the same thing, then I don't know how to answer this without seeing your file.

Comment: Yes it's the same as scrolling the middle mouse button. It didn't fix my problem :( I  don't understand why I can't add more horizontal cuts or aka a full cut (see 2nd picture)

Comment: Check for double edges or double vertices that could be causing non-quad geometry. A cut will stop when it meets a "non-quad" face.

Comment: I clicked remove doubles and it fixed it, it removed 2 vertices. BUT please help me understand this like the idiot I am because I have no idea what was happening. What are vertices and nonquad geometry? how can there be a double "edge"?  And most of all how do I (in future) myself locate those problems? I mean I had no idea that I had these "2 vertices" causing the problem? how do I see them? and how do I identify them myself on any object? Also another question was after I added cuts how do I make sure that theres the same length inbetween each cut (see 1st pic) and how do I remove them?